# return value from node js(deployed on aws ) to unity

Tags: c#, node.js, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine

This is my node.js and c# code.

```
//Node.Js function
exports.test = function (req, res) {
  console.log("test called");
  res.status(200).send("test called")
}
//C# code 
IEnumerator test()
{
WWW www = new WWW("link here:1338/test");
yield return www;
print(www.text);
}
```

When I access it using postman it return "test called" but when i run it in browser or in unity it gives " no such file or directory". Please help me i have never done this before.

Comment: can you show us the postman also? in postman under send/save there is a code button.  The cURL or C# restsharp is fine.

Comment: `when i run it in browser or in unity` so this sounds like a general implementation error on the server side not directly related to Unity...